# Paired t-test question for spatially distributed data

Tags: t-test, spatial, paired-data

I have spatially distributed data at 50 locations for pre and post rainfall. So, 2 data points for each station. All the sites are different. Can I use paired t-test on this data?

Comment: Just to be sure this is clear, can you give the data you have for two or three of the sites?

Comment: There might be spatial correlations that must be accointed for somehow! How large are interpoint distances? That is, how many of the stations might be influenced by the same system of rainclouds?